# Different Membership Status Rules for Different Memberships?

Tags: civimember

We are using CiviCRM to manage data for several levels of our organization. At the moment, rules around grace/lapse periods are not standardized across the organization. Is it possible to apply different membership status rules to different membership types?

1. Membership A. Current 0-12 months from start; Grace until +2 months after membership end date.
2. Membership B: Current 0-12 months after start; Grace until 1 month after membership end date.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Rachel

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with out-of-the-box CiviCRM and I am not aware of any extension that provides that functionality.

As I am not a developer I can't comment on how difficult it would be to write an extension to provide what you would like, however, even if it is an easy task, extensions need to be maintained as CiviCRM is upgraded.

Grace periods have usually been arbitrarily determined at some time in the past   so in a situation like this is I would go to the parties involved and say something like "Managing membership with CiviCRM will deliver lots of benefits, (enumerate) but the grace period is going to need to be standardized across the organization." and leave it to them (or the common boss in their management chains) to decide whether it will be one or two months.